# Find the derivative of a composite function using only the limits definition

Tags: functions, derivatives, definition

Let the function $f, g, h$ be a surjective function $\forall x \in R$, if $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}f(x) = g(x)$ and $h(x) = f(ax + b)$ where a, b is a constant and a $\ne$ 0.

Proof that $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}h(x) = ag(ax + b)$ **using** only the limits definition of derivative.

Comment: How far did you get? Write up the definition for $h$.

Comment: I don't know if this gonna be right, but I let $u = ax +b$, and so I get the $h'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\text{f(u + h) - f(u)}}{\text{h}}$ that's how far I could get. Also I was able to proof it but I was using the "**chain rule**" and not the limits definition

Comment: If you write it in the question body, you'll more likely to receive upvotes instead of downvotes.

Comment: Sorry, I will make sure to do it next time.

Comment: You can still edit your question. (Though it doesn't really matter now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the algebraic properties of limits.

Also, you can do it step by step: first step is with $b=0$: let $u(x):=f(ax)$, then 
$$\frac d{dx}u(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a(x+h)) - f(ax)}h$$
Here observe that $h_2:=ah\to 0$, and use $\frac{f(ax+h_2)-f(ax)}{h_2}\to \frac d{dx}f(ax)$. The case $a=0$ can be separately handled.

The next step would be with $a=1$, so that $h(x)=u(x+b)$.

Then combine.

Comment: Thankyou very much!